# Obtención de medidas de triángulos presentes en imágenes en OpenCV

Tags: python, imagen, opencv

quisiera saber, como obtener medidas de triángulos, que encuentre la cámara, con OpenCV y Python. ¿Literatura o blogs que me recomienden? Acepto ideas